# jQuery POST default post fields

Tags: php, jquery, post

I know that we can add some default options (settings) to POST request in jQuery, but my question is the following : **Can I add a default field with value to the POST so it will be sent with each post request?**

For example : if I have : `?name=John&age=20` and I send them with `$.post()` method, I want PHP to receive it as : `?name=John&age=20&defaultField1=defaultValue1`

P.S: I know that I can add fields to the form using `append()` or methods like this or directly to the array of data before `.serialize()`, but it will be much better if I will be able to add it as default option. *(Field I need will be request token, so PHP won't process datas if this key is not set)*

Comment: stuff in a hidden form field with that name=value when php's building the page originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest option would be to wrap all your calls to `$.post` in an internal function that appends this parameter before the actual call to `$.post`.

Any time you want to send a post request, call your `custom_post_function` which will append your default parameters automatically.

Here is some super (over) simplified pseudo-code to demonstrate:

```
function custom_post_function( parameters ){
  // manipulate your parameters before the actual call to $.post
  parameters += "some_special_suff";
  $.post( parameters );
}
```

Comment: OP, even if it were possible to set this as a global jQuery default (which it may be), Lix's wrapper function solution would still be preferable. In fact I'd think very carefully before setting *any* jQuery.ajax defaults / `$.ajaxSetup` / etc. Otherwise one day when you hit a situation where you need to make a POST request *without* that extra parameter (to an external resource, perhaps), or you want to swap out jQuery for an alternative XHR library, you'll have a massive headache...

Answer (score 0):

May be using a fixed custom header (then read it to process the request or not) with [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) for all request or use [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'yourdefaultvalue' }
});
```

or using beforeSend (You can also use this with individual request, if needed):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'yourdefaultvalue');
    }
});
```